# Jquery code not executing after navigating from another component. Only executes on reload on angular 4

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

I am new and working on a angular 4 project. I wrote some jquery code to append elements on view but the code is only executing on page reload. It is not executing after navigating form another page using angular route. I am not being able to figure out what to do. My code is like this.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild, Renderer2, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  public categories: any;
  public response: any;


  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2, private authService: AuthService, private http: Http, private routes: Router, private dataService: DataService) {

  });

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.getCategories();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    jQuery('.newOption').on('click', function (this) {
      console.log(this);
      console.log(jQuery(this).data('value'));
      this.searchByCategory = jQuery(this).data('value');
      this.searchProducts();
    });
  }

  getCategories() {
    let body = {

    }
    this.dataService.globalAjaxGet('category/list').then((res) => {
      this.response = res;
      this.categories = this.response.data.categories;

      //this code will run on reload but doesnot executes when navigating from another component. 
      jQuery('.newSelect').prepend('<div class="selectedOption">Browse Categories</div><div class="newOptions"></div>');
      for (let cat of this.categories) {
        jQuery('.newOptions').append('<div id="option_' + cat.id + '" class="newOption" data-value="' + cat.id + '">' + cat.category + '</div>')

      }
      this.ngOnInit();

    }).catch((e) => {

    });
  }

}
```

And the main thing is this the header component and it is included in another component. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please use this `declare var jQuery: any;` in app.module.ts (root module) which every component will make use of. I tried it. Ref https://angular-keevf6.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0):

Please move this line 
`declare var jQuery: any;` in app.module.ts (root module) 
which every component will make use of. I tried it.

Ref [https://angular-keevf6.stackblitz.io]

Comment: where do i put it inside app module

Comment: Refer the attached link for sample demo.

[Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-keevf6)

Comment: this site is blank nothing is here or i am not being able to access this site

Comment: error cant find jQuery. After declaring it in app module only the header component says it cant find jQuery

Comment: you can use `$` symbol instead of jQuery based on your jquery version.